# How to implement voting in Rails without voting gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, voting, voting-system

I have created a hacker news clone and I am trying to implement a voting system that ranks from most voted to least voted, based on the past 7 days. I know there are several gems to do this but I would like to do it once manually before using a gem.

First issue I am having, is with multiple votes. I want to have each user able to vote on as many links as they want but with a limit of one vote per link. I tried to make this happen in my `votes_controller` but it is only allowing the links themselves to have one vote total instead of the user having one vote per link. Here is my method in `votes_controller` :

```
 def create
    @vote = Vote.new(voter_params)
    if @vote.save
      redirect_to links_path, notice: "Thanks for voting!"
    else
      redirect_to links_path, notice: "Sorry, you can only vote on a link once."  
    end
  end
```

My `schema.rb` consists of `users`, `links`, and `votes` with a `user_id` attribute in both `links` and `votes` as listed here :

```
 create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "link_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

How can  I refactor my current action to allow votes for any link but only one vote per user?

Ok, my second and last question is, once I have that voting issue squared away, how can I sort them from most voted, to least voted, based on the past 7 days, going through the postgres server approach of course. It just seems to me that going through the db is more efficient. I'd appreciate any insight I can get, I am totally stumped, thanks!!

Here is my link model to give a better idea :

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :url, :presence => true, :url => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  def self.sort_by_votes
    sorted_votes = Link.all.sort_by { |link| link.votes.count }
    sorted_votes.reverse
  end
end
```

and here is my view :

```
<% if current_user %>
<p style="float:right; padding-right: 10px;"> Logged in as: <%= current_user.name %> </p>
<% end %>
<div class="container" id="content">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="float:right"><%= link_to "New Link", new_link_path %></button><br><br>
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="stories">
    <% @links.sort_by_votes.each do |link| %>
          <%= form_for link.votes.new do |f| %>
                   <%= f.hidden_field :link_id %>
                   <%= f.submit '▲' %>
                   <% end %>
          <%= "#{link.votes.count} votes " %>
          <%= link_to link.description, link.url %>
          <small><%= "(#{link.url})" %></small>
          <span class="date"><%= link.created_at.to_time.strftime("%b %-d, %Y @ %-I:%M%P") %></span>
          <br>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            <%= link_to "Delete", link, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "are you sure about that?" } %>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            <%= link_to "Comment", link_path(link)%>
          </button><hr/>
      <% end %>
</tbody>

</div>
```

Comment: You can create custom validation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use validations for this:

```
class Vote
  #...
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :link_id }
```

Relationship counters are rather complex depending on your db and also generally produce complex time consuming queries. I'd use the `counter_cache` option. There's a [nice post](http://hiteshrawal.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/rails-counter-cache.html) about how to use those.

```
$ rails g migration add_votes_counter_to_link votes_count:integer
class AddVotesCounterToLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :links, :votes_count, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
$ rake db:migrate

class Vote
  belongs_to :link, counter_cache: true
end

class Link
  has_many :votes

  scope :most_voted, -> do
    where(created_at: (Time.now - 7.days)..Time.now ) # created 7 days ago
    .order('votes_count DESC')                        # ordered by votes_count
    .limit(100)                                       # first 100
  end
```

Then you can do things like:

```
Link.most_voted
```

Comment: Word. I don't think I've seen that `-> do` script before, is that coffeescript? I tried implementing that change by adding the column and deleting my sort_by_votes method but even though it was able to let multiple people vote on the same task which is a small victory, it did not sort anything. Do I need to nest that scope call into a function? As far as I know DESC is a db query, yes? Can you help me understand how to implement it into my model so it executes? Thanks dude!

Comment: I have also added my link model and view to help illustrate my trouble with integrating the counter cache. Sidebar: I am using Rails, not coffeescript

Comment: `->(args) { }` is ruby 1.9.3 syntax for procs, ruby's anonymous functions.

Comment: I see, thanks so much for your help! It all makes very good sense. Now I can just query from the db!